# GoogleMobileAds framework installation for MobiDevelops's fork of robovm

Tags: ios, android-studio, libgdx, admob

I'm struggling with the installation of the GoogleMobileAds framework to make the IOS version of my libgdx app work.

I'm using the Robovm fork by MobiDevelops (http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/)

When i try to compile the app i get this error:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMobileAds
```

Full error: https://pastebin.com/raw/uVAs2Mp1

here are my `robovm.xml`, `Build.gradle` files & my IOS libs folder :

`robovm.xml` : https://pastebin.com/raw/SpKUdtBd

`Build.gralde` : https://pastebin.com/raw/iG54UR1N

libs folder : [image: libs]

i'm obviously doing something wrong, but what ? i'm not familiar with this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libs folder with GoogleMobileAds has to be located in root of ios module, not in build folder. as you have specified the path to look for frameworks as:

```
    <frameworkPaths>
        <path>libs</path>
    </frameworkPaths>
```

and it is relative to root of module.